# How To Get Search Query From Multiple Columns in Database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have search form to get information from table named books.

Right now i'm using this controller

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $keyword = $request->input('keyword');
    $query = Book::where('judul', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%');

    $book_list = $query->paginate(5);
    $pagination = $book_list->appends($request->except('page'));
    $total_book = $book_list->total();
    return view('dashboards.index', compact('book_list', 'keyword', 'pagination', 'total_book'));
}
```

The problem is the data that i get from the request only available for **judul**. it just show empty result if the input keyword search addressed to search writter or publisher

I want the search form able to get data from other columns named **writters** and **publisher**

Is there any method to get data from multiple column?

Comment: using a search plugin would make things a lot easier for you. https://github.com/nicolaslopezj/searchable

Comment: @SapneshNaik hi many thanks for the advice, i will give it a try but since i'm begginer in laravel and PHP i need to solve this in 'manual' method.

Comment: @YudyAnanda Do you mean you need to match the same keyword with  writters and publisher ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Hi, what i mean is I need the seach form able to get data from 3 of them (column: judul, publisher, writter) not only judul

Answer (score 22):

You can use orwhere to fullfill this, like this

```
Book::where(function ($query) use($keyword) {
        $query->where('judul', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
           ->orWhere('writters', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%');
      })
->get();
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: what if you need and "andWhere()"?

Comment: @ahnbizcad nice question. For andWhere you can remove the or from orWhere it will consider and operator automatically.

Answer (score 3):

You can execute conditional queries in many ways.

**1.** You can use [`when()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#conditional-clauses):

```
Book::when($keyword, function ($q) use ($keyword) {
        return $q->where('judul', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%');;
    })
    ->get();
```

**2.** Use the [where closure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#parameter-grouping):

```
Book::where(function($q) use ($keyword, $request) {
        if ($request) {
            $q->where('judul', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%');
        }
    })
    ->get();
```

**3.** Do this:

```
$books = Book::query();

if ($request) {
    $books = $books->where('judul', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%');
}

$books = $books->get();
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, so which part i should change? it looks like still fetch **judul** only, what about others columns (writter and publisher)?

Comment: @YudyAnanda if these columns are in the same table, these examples will fetch all the columns. I think you're adding something like `select()` to the query if you don't get some of the columns.

Comment: i try `$books = Book::query();..` it thow me to a BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74: Method paginate does not exist.

Comment: @YudyAnanda I've just tried this on 5.3 and 5.5 and it works fine. For 5.2 you could try `newQuery()` instead of `query()`