# Laravel Eloquent condition with "with" relationship datas which impact the output

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Here is my code :

```
$search = request()->get('search');

    if(Auth::user()->hasRole('admin') || true) {
        list($orderBy, $orderDirection) = explode('.', request()->get('sort_by'));
        $prestations = Prestation::with(
            [
            'service' => function($service) use($search){
                $service->select(['id','name']);
                ->where('name', 'regexp', "/$search/i"); <--- HERE THE PROBLEM, i get some "null" values in the output, it's not a really condition to display or not
            },
            'facility' => function($facility) {
                $facility->select(['id','name']);
            }
            ]
        )
            ->where('name', 'regexp', "/$search/i") <-- I want to do this with service name
            ->orderBy($orderBy, $orderDirection)
            ->simplePaginate(50);

        $res = [
            'results' => $prestations,
            'total' => Prestation::all()->count(),
        ];

        return $res;
```

I want to do a where condition on my 'service:name' which impacts the output really and don't display datas where the value is "null", like the `->where('name', 'regexp', "/$search/i")`, but I don't know how to access to the "service:name" of "with" relationship.

Thank you and happy new year !

Comment: you should check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48089966/how-to-get-search-query-from-multiple-columns-in-database

Comment: You have to use `collection helper` `where` for this, fetch records without where clause and then use `where` helper to get desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using LIKE operator:

```
$prestations = Prestation::with(
        [
            'service' => function($service) use($searchTerm){
                $service->select(['id','name'])->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$searchTerm%");
            },
        ]
    )->orderBy($orderBy, $orderDirection)->simplePaginate(50);
```

1. If you want to search records that contains your search term then use `LIKE '%$searchTerm%'`
2. If you want to search records that starts with your search term then use `LIKE '$searchTerm%'`
3. And if you want to search records that ends with your search term then use `LIKE '%$searchTerm'`

Hope this helps you out

Comment: Hi, thank for your suggest, my problem is that i want to do this where after the "with()"

Comment: The where condition after the with will be applied to the parent model i.e. Prestation. So either define this where in the service relationship directly or use relationship condition as stated above as this is the best practice in laravel to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use whereHas for this

```
$prestations = Prestation::whereHas('service', function($subQuery) use($search) {
                $subQuery->where('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
            })->with(
    [
        'service' => function($service) use($search){
            $service->select(['id','name'])->where('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
        },
    ]
)->orderBy($orderBy, $orderDirection)->simplePaginate(50);
```