# How can I search with multiple columns in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am very new in Laravel, I try to search with one column and this is my code. But now I want to search with multiple columns - how can I do that?

My controller :

```
public function search_pers(Request $request)
{
    $mle = $request->input('mle');
    $listpers = Personne::where('mle', 'LIKE', '%'.$mle.'%')->get();

    return view('frontend.etat_civil', ['personnes' => $listpers]);
}
```

Comment: Does this help?: [How to Create Multiple Where Clause Query Using Laravel Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/how-to-create-multiple-where-clause-query-using-laravel-eloquent)

Comment: it doesn't help me

Comment: How about this?: [How To Get Search Query From Multiple Columns in Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48089966/how-to-get-search-query-from-multiple-columns-in-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand what you need is an orWhere condition:

```php
 public function search_pers(Request $request)
    {
      $mle = $request->input('mle');
      $listpers = Personne::where('mle', 'LIKE', '%'.$mle.'%')->orWhere('nom','like','%'.$mle.'%')->get();

      return view('frontend.etat_civil', ['personnes' => $listpers]);
    }
```

Another alternative and probably a better one is to use fulltext search.
[MySQL Fulltext search](https://victoryoalli.me/mysql-fulltext-search)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array

```
     Personne::where([
        ['col1', '=', 'value1'],
        ['col2', '<>', 'value2'],
        [Your_col, OPERATOR, value],
        ...
    ])
```

or in your  case

```
      $str = "concat('%',".$mle .",'%')";
      $listpers = Personne::where([
            ['mle', 'LIKE', $str],
            ['col1', '=', 'value1'],
            ['col2', '<>', 'value2'],
            [Your_col, OPERATOR, value],
      )->get();
```

Comment: @SaraAlaoui  answer  updated ..  hope is  more clear

Comment: yes ,  `  $listpers = Personne::where([
            ['mle', 'LIKE', '%'.$mle.'%'],
            ['nom', 'LIKE', '%'.$mle.'%'],

              ])->get();  `   
but it gives nothing

Comment: you have error?? ,..  show the code you are actually using  ..anyway answer  updated .with a new suggestion